# Create multiple possible email addresses based on names in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
  firstname   lastname                     email_address  \
0      Doug     Watson  douglas.watson@dignityhealth.org   
1      Nick   Holekamp    nick.holekamp@rankenjordan.org   
2       Rob  Schreiner        rob.schriener@wellstar.org   
3    Austin   Phillips       austin.phillips@precmed.com   
4     Elise     Geiger               egeiger@puracap.com   
5      Paul      Urick       purick@diplomatpharmacy.com   
6   Michael   Obringer    michael.obringer@lashgroup.com   
7     Craig   Heneghan           cheneghan@west-ward.com   
8     Kathy      Hirst       kathleen.hirst@sunovion.com   
9    Stefan  Bluemmers   stefan.bluemmers@grunenthal.com   

                               companyname  
0                           Dignity Health  
1  Ranken Jordan Pediatric Bridge Hospital  
2                   WellStar Health System  
3         Precision Medical Products, Inc.  
4                              puracap.com  
5              Diplomat Specialty Pharmacy  
6                               Lash Group  
7                West-Ward Pharmaceuticals  
8                 Sunovion Pharmaceuticals  
9                         Grünenthal Group
```

How could I create possible email addresses using common email patterns as such: `firstlast@example.com, first.last@example.com, f.last@example.com, lastF@example.com, first_last@example.com, firstL@example.com`, etc.

```
df['email1'] = df.firstname.str.lower() + '.' + df.lastname.str.lower() + '@' + df.companyname.str.replace('\s+', '').str.lower() + '.com'
print(df['email1'])
```

Out:

```
0                           doug.watson@dignityhealth.com
1       nick.holekamp@rankenjordanpediatricbridgehospi...  --->problematic
2                  rob.schreiner@wellstarhealthsystem.com
3       austin.phillips@precisionmedicalproducts,inc..com  --->problematic
4                            elise.geiger@puracap.com.com  --->problematic
                              ...                        
9995              terry.hanley@kempersportsmanagement.com
9996                          christine.marks@geocomp.com
9997                               darryl.rickner@doe.com
9998                     lalit.sharma@lovelylifestyle.com
9999                              parul.dutt@infibeam.com
```

Some of them seems quite problematic, anyone could help to solve this issue? Thanks a lot.

EDITED:

`print(df)` after applying @Sajith Herath's solution:

Out:

```
  firstname  lastname                                        companyname  \
0      Nick  Holekamp  Ranken                                        ...   

                                               email  
0                       nick.                    ...
```

Comment: You can add a way of pre-processing the company name before using it as an email domain. For example, removing spaces and punctuations, checking length, detecting variations of `.com`, removing abbreviations (`,inc`), etc.

Comment: It seems quite complicated than I thought.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? You already have an email column in your data. Maybe there is another way to fix the original problem you're tackling?

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I was asked to propose possible email addresses based on paterns to users.

Comment: Would using the domain name from the email field be sufficient? You can create different combinations of `first/last` and append `@domain.com` to it. If that doesn't work, then the only option is to do the suggested pre-processing on the company name before using it as a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method to create permutations of username with different separators and define a max length that simplify the domain using company name as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import random

data = {"firstname":["Nick"],"lastname":["Holekamp"],"companyname":["Ranken \
                                        Jordan Pediatric Bridge Hospital"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

max_char = 5
emails = []

def simplify_domain(text):
    if len(text)>max_char:
        text = ''.join([c for c in text if c.isupper()])
        return text.lower()
    return text.replace("\s+","").lower()

def username_permutations(first_name,last_name):
  # define separators 
  separators = [".", "_", "-"]
  #lower case
  combinations = list(map(lambda x:f"{first_name.lower()}{x} \
                           {last_name.lower()}",separators))

  #append a random number to tail
  n = random.randint(1, 100) 
  combinations.extend(list(map(lambda x:f"{x}{n}",combinations)))
  return combinations

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    usernames = username_permutations(row["firstname"],row["lastname"])
    email_permutations = list(map(lambda x: f" \
                    {x}@{simplify_domain(row['companyname'])}.com",usernames))
    emails.append(','.join(email_permutations))

df["email"] = emails
```

Final result will be `nick.holekamp@rjpbh.com,nick_holekamp@rjpbh.com,nick-holekamp@rjpbh.com,nick.holekamp66@rjpbh.com,nick_holekamp66@rjpbh.com,nick-holekamp66@rjpbh.com`

you can modify `simplify_domain` method to validate given string such as removing `inc` or `.com` values

Comment: Thanks so much, but it raise a `NameError: name 'simplify' is not defined`, maybe some typos in your code?

Comment: No problem. What your test result by the way, I tested your code, but the output seems not correct email addresses. Please check my update in the question.

Comment: it seems works for me https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ldu0BkckrkQvAf0j3IMoWTzSmrjmicas?usp=sharing

Comment: Test with jupyter notebook, it works as well. But with my real data, it raises `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from `NaN` and `float` values in those name columns?

Comment: yes. you should preprocess(drop or fill) `NaN` and `float` values and make sure you only pass strings